# Find closest and insert before an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have three buttons which clone a `div` and it will show the `div` before the clicked button. Currently when clicking on a button, the `div` will appear before all three buttons. I need on click of the button to insert that `div` only before the clicked button.

```js
var toAppend = $('#appendFullWidthAll').children();

$('#showContent').click(function() {
  toAppend.clone().insertBefore('.show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="appendFullWidthAll" class="d-none">
  <ul>
    <li>Test Content</li>
    <li>Test Content</li>
    <li>Test Content</li>
    <li>Test Content</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="1">
  <a class="btn btn-primary show" id="showContent">Click Here</a>
</div>

<div class="2">
  <a class="btn btn-primary show" id="showContent">Click Here</a>
</div>

<div class="3">
  <a class="btn btn-primary show" id="showContent">Click Here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Having multiple IDs on a page is invalid HTML. Change them to classes instead, or use different IDs.

Comment: There are some issue inside here, first is do not use same id, if u really need a group of elements, use class. so here, if u change each button id to showContent1, showContent2 and showContent3, and $('.btn').click(... this will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *inserting before* of any element that have the class `show`, that is your main problem. The solution is to capture the element you have clicked using `$(this)` selector, like this:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    toAppend.clone().insertBefore($(this));
});
```

Comment: You don't need to convert `this` to jQuery in this context as the `insertBefore()` method will take `this` too.

Answer (score 2):

Please, don`t use the same id 3-times. the id of element needs be uniques for the HTML page.
Please, try this way to achieve your goal

```
var toAppend = $('#appendFullWidthAll').children();

$('.btn.show').click(function() {
   const clickedButton = $(this);
   toAppend.clone().insertBefore(clickedButton);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, IDs in HTML must be unique. Now, to apply any action to the element that raised the event, use the keyword `this` inside the event. But remember that `this` is a JavaScript keyword, so use `$(this)` to convert it to jQuery:

```js
var toAppend = $('#appendFullWidthAll').children();

$('.show').click(function() {
  toAppend.clone().insertBefore(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="appendFullWidthAll" class="d-none">
  <ul>
    <li>Test Content</li>
    <li>Test Content</li>
    <li>Test Content</li>
    <li>Test Content</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="1">
  <a class="btn btn-primary show">Click Here</a>
</div>

<div class="2">
  <a class="btn btn-primary show">Click Here</a>
</div>

<div class="3">
  <a class="btn btn-primary show">Click Here</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element you have clicked using the `$(this)` selector inside the `click` event listener. Also, don't use the same `id` attribute for multiple elements, I have replaced the `click` listener using the `show` class selector instead of the wrong one that uses the `id` attribute. Check next example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var toAppend = $('#appendFullWidthAll').children();

    $('.show').click(function()
    {
        var clickedButton = $(this)
        toAppend.clone().insertBefore(clickedButton);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="appendFullWidthAll" class="d-none">
<ul>
<li>Test Content</li>
<li>Test Content</li>
<li>Test Content</li>
<li>Test Content</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="1">
<a class="btn btn-primary show" id="showContent1">Click Here</a>
</div>

<div class="2">
<a class="btn btn-primary show" id="showContent2">Click Here</a>
</div>

<div class="3">
<a class="btn btn-primary show" id="showContent3">Click Here</a>
</div>
```